# how to access a protected variable in a sister trait

Tags: scala

I'm using a Logging trait in my application and I'm curious whether it's possible to access a protected variable from the Logging trait.

This is what I have:

```
class MyClass extends ExternalTrait with Logging

trait ExternalTrait {
  protected val protectedVar = "secret?"
}

trait Logging {
  if(this.isInstanceOf[OtherTrait]) 
    this.asInstanceOf[OtherTrait].protectedVar
}
```

but the access to the protected variable is restricted when accessing in this manner. Is there some other way to access the protectedVar from the Logging trait?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you definitely know that `Logging` later is mixed in to `ExternalTrait` you can place a self reference:

```
trait Logging { this: ExternalTrait =>
  val value = protectedVar
}
```

Of course, if there can be logging traits which do not extend/mixin other traits self references are not suitable. In such a case I would subclass `Logging` to handle the different behavior.

```
trait Logging
trait StandAloneLogging extends Logging
trait BasedOnLogging extends Logging { this: ExternalTrait =>
  val value = protectedVar
}
```

Comment: I was hoping for detection and using just the one Logging trait as a magical solution afforded only by Scala, although the extension you've suggested isn't too intrusive.